# Would like to script on Google Sheets a way to remove certain rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The first row has a column heading: First Name, Last Name, Email, Grade, Date
We have instances where people need to re-take tests and therefore will have another entry into the spreadsheet, what we are looking for, is a way that if someone re-takes the test and then adds their new data into the spreadsheet, we can automatically remove their old information

So, I have made some progress, this script removes duplicate rows, but exactly duplicate, so I need to somehow edit it to only look at the first 2 columns and then delete the oldest entry based on the Date column:

```html
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: And how is data added into the spreadsheet?  A Google Form? A Google Apps Script? Can you provide an example?

Comment: They add the data from Zapier

Comment: And how does that work?

Comment: I've never used Zapier and I have no script example from you regarding how duplicates are removed so I have no understandable point of reference to answer your question.

Comment: When they complete a test on the platform, it inputs the user's data into the spreadsheet, with pass/fail, score and date

Comment: My question is how does user data get entered into the spreadsheet?

Comment: So now the script you have provided simply removes duplicates it doesn't enter any data.

Comment: Zapier uses a workflow that when an assessment is completed in Kajabi, it triggers the workflow and adds the users data into a spreadsheet row in Google Sheets

Comment: What is Kajabi? Please describe the workflow and how data is entered into Google Sheets.  Please be specific

Comment: Kajabi is a learning platform where people can watch videos and take some tests. The workflow is a pre-configured one on Zapier, all we had to do was link the Kajabi project to the Google sheets document and it done it all for us, so can't really confirm what that does in much more details. That part of it is fine though, what I would like to do is amend the script in the main body I added above, as this can delete duplicate rows, but edit it to look at column A and B only, and delete based on which is oldest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to compare the first two columns in each row instead of the full row.

Therefore, you should just compare indexes `0` and `1`, and not the full array (something which you are doing with `join`). You could just replace this line:

```
if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
```

With this one:

```
if (row[0] === newData[j][0] && row[1] === newData[j][1]) {
```

#### Edit:

If you want to keep the newest, and not the oldest, loop your 2D array in reverse instead. For example, you can use [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) when retrieving the source data:

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reverse();
```

Alternatively, use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to loop in reverse:

```
for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

More in general, consider using [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeDuplicates(Integer)).

#### Edit 2:

If you have headers, just use `reverse` again when setting the values in order to keep the original order:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData.reverse());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, definitely progress. Just tested this and it has now deleted the duplicate rows, however it deletes all of the newest data, so still working on having it delete the oldest data as per the Date column

Comment: @CraigSummers Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @lamblichus that worked, but, the first row with the headings moved to the bottom of the rows, and the first row of data is not in the headings row if that makes sense

Comment: @CraigSummers If you have headers, just use `reverse` again when setting the values: `sheet.getRange(2, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData.reverse());` (it would have been better to not include the headers in your range in the first place, and use `Range.clearContent()` instead of `Sheet.clearContents()`, but nvm).

Comment: @lamblichus, that worked, but just had to change sheet.getRange(2, 1, to sheet.getRange(1, 1,

Comment: @CraigSummers Oops yes, that was a typo sorry.